# Merge based on latest Date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to left join Dataframe 'Raw' with another dataframe 'acknowledgement'

**Raw**

```
LogId
1233
1234
1235
```

acknowledgement

```
LogId  Reason       Time
1233   Valid        13/09/20 09:45:19
1233   Not Valid    13/09/20 17:23:20
1234   Not Valid    25/09/20 14:56:34
1234   Valid        21/09/20 12:23:12
```

My code:

```
pd.merge(raw,acknowledgement,on='Log Id',how='left')
```

Now when i do the left join on 'Log Id' the values are getting duplicated.

The desired output should take only the latest days remarks for that particular 'Log Id'

```
LogId  Reason       Time
1233   Not Valid    13/09/20 17:23:20
1234   Not Valid    25/09/20 14:56:34
1235   #N/A          #N/A
```

Comment: This is almost a dup as @NYCCoder pointed out. Drop the duplicates on `acknowledgement` then merge.

Comment: My opinion is it is duplicate, because merge solution is in question, only need `ack = acknowledgement.loc[acknowledgement.groupby('LogId')['Time'].idxmax()]`, but is possible I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `groupby` + `idxmax` to get the indices of max values of `Time` per `LogId` then use these indices to filter the dataframe then left merge it with `raw` :

```
ack = acknowledgement.loc[acknowledgement.groupby('LogId')['Time'].idxmax()]
raw.merge(ack, on='LogId', how='left')
```

Alternatively you can also try:

```
m = acknowledgement.sort_values('Time').duplicated('LogId', keep='last')
raw.merge(acknowledgement[~m], on='LogId', how='left')
```

---

```
   LogId     Reason                Time
0   1233  Not Valid 2020-09-13 17:23:20
1   1234  Not Valid 2020-09-25 14:56:34
2   1235        NaN                 NaT
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223791/discussion-on-answer-by-shubham-sharma-merge-based-on-latest-date-in-pandas).